# How to stop toast message when using GPS at application exit

Tags: android, gps, message, toast

I followed some tutorial on how to detect the GPS location and to display it in a Toast message. The problem was that the toast message kept showing even after the application was exited. (It was running in the background). I have tried to stop it by using close(), within overriden method onStop(), onResume() and onPause().

Comment: Here is my solution that worked well for me:
    @Override
    public void onPause() {     
     if (toastMessage!=null){
       locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
     }
     super.onPause();
    }
Note that you need to call super.onPause() after removing the updates!

Comment: you need to show some code

Comment: @tyczj I gave the solution above! It worked fine for me!

Comment: If the method you suggested above worked please create an answer and mark this question as answered. Do not use a comment to propose an answer.

Comment: @E.Odebugg Sorry for the inconvenience, I wanted to do that but I got this message:

Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.
We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

I will post the answer again, after 8 hs.

Comment: This was a pretty localized issues based on the logic I see in the comment.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that rule...